# Subject and objects of “Do you know what’s the difference between us and her?”

Tags: grammar

“Do you know what’s the difference between us and her?”

In this sentence, which one is the the subject?

And is using the object forms(’us’ and ‘her’) correct here?

Comment: The sentences in the question title and body do not match. You might wanna [edit] your question to fix that.

Comment: The subject of the matrix (main) clause is "you". The subject of the subordinate interrogative clause is "what". Yes, you are using the correct pronouns.